# How to access win32 console App Data in VC++ MFC GUI

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, console-application

I have two apps:

1. Win32 Console App.
2. MFC GUI App.

I wanted to execute the console app in MFC GUI and I am want to get data from that Console app and display them in GUI.

I get this error while compiling:

> fatal error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]

Is IPC the answer?

Answer (score 2):

The build error you get is irrelevant with what you are trying to achieve. To capture the output of a console application in a window, I refer you to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/quickwin.aspx) excellent article in [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/).